# stuck in the title screen after the insert of SSD samsung asus N552VW

Tags: boot, ssd, freeze, asus-laptop

Hi I bought a ssd samsung 860 evo 1 tb.

When I replace the hard disk with the SSD the computer freeze on the screen "ASUS in search of incredible".

I have the last version of bios installed, the 304 in my asus N552VW and when the hard disk is inside the pc and the SSD is attacked with a USB adapter the computer starts normally.

I have to do a clean installation of windows 10 on the SSD, but boot operations are blocked because of freeze.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: The EFI partition isn't configured correctly _(this is why it's recommended to use Windows' native tools [`DISM`] to clone partitions)_, which is why it freezes on the UEFI boot screen.  Boot a [Windows install USB](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), once the GUI loads press **`SHIFT`+`F10`** & issue the command: `bootrec /fixmbr && bootrec /rebuildbcd` & reboot once it completes.  If this doesn't fix the bootloader issue,re-create the EFI partition by copying over the EFI boot files to the EFI partition from `%WinDir%\Boot\EFI`, then re-issue the previous command

Comment: You can try correcting the EFI partition with `bcdboot`, but if the following doesn't work, re-image the partitions on the original drive using `DISM` via the commands under the [**Imaging**](https://superuser.com/a/1503102/529800) section and re-configure the partitions as listed under **Configure Partitions**.  Follow the previous comment to get to a terminal, then `bcdboot C:\windows /s` or `bcdboot C:\windows /s S:` _(replace `C:` with the correct drive letter for the Windows OS partition)_.  Once done, re-issue: `bootrec /fixmbr && bootrec /rebuildbcd`

Comment: question: the SSD is empty, i haven't done any cloning operation. I just wanted to reinstall everything cleanly, inserting the usb and start the boot operation. The Pc start normally if the hdd is connected via usb or if only the usb stick is attached. 
Can it be a Bios problem?